# Unable to fetch data in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm a beginner and trying to learn selenium webdriver. I have connected the database in Eclipse, but when I try to execute the query it gives me the error

```
Oracle JDBC driver loaded ok.
DB Connected Successfuly
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getString(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1270)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:498)
    at regressionTesting.TestDBConnect.main(TestDBConnect.java:34)
```

Below is my complete code.

```
    package regressionTesting;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TestDBConnect {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception

    {
        //Accessing driver from the JAR file 
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        System.out.println("Oracle JDBC driver loaded ok.");

        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin://:localhost:1602:mydb","root","root");
        System.out.println("DB Connected Successfuly");

        //jdbc:oracle:thin:@epwfst1db.dev.qintra.com:1602:epwfst1 --> this is the database
        //epwf_app --> this is the username
        //epwf_app_epwfst1 --> this is the passwd

        //Below we create our query
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from epwf.payment where created_user_nm = '1600STOUTST7000'");

        //Below we create variable to execute the query
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        while(result.next());

        String amount = result.getString("payment_amt");
        String baid = result.getString("billing_application_accnt_id");
        String status = result.getString("status_cd");

        System.out.println("Amount: " + amount);
        System.out.println("BAID: " + baid);
        System.out.println("Status: " + status);
    }

}
```

for the query that i have mentioned above. The columns are way more than what i wanted in the result. Do you think, because of that the error is coming.

Any help will be highly appreciated. As I mentioned, i'm new to this, so if you could please be as detailed as possible. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have incorrect syntax in your code

your `while` loop doesn't contain any code (check below for more info)

```
while(result.next());
```

Instead you should use

```
while (result.next() {


}
```

You get the exception because you try to access a column value after processing the resultset.

Example when **exception** is thrown:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    String s = rs.getString(0);
 }
 String s = rs.getString(0); //this will throw Exhausted resultset
```

Ending a `while` or `if` with `;` terminates the condition after first line of code

Example:

```
 if (true);
     System.out.println("this will be printed out");
```

If you want to invoke at least 2 instructions you have to put it in parenthessis `{}`